# session disconnect the client after smart card is removed

Tags: java, ssl, session-state, smartcard

i implemented a strong authentification with cac smart card on apache,tomcat and IIS 7.5 but the problem is when the client remove the smart card from the reader he still have full access to the server.
so how to creat a authentificator mamager or session disconnect client after smart card is  removed.

Sessions can be in one of two states, Connected or Disconnected:

**Connected**: Every session with a connected status is displayed on client. The session is automatically disconnected when the user removes the smart card or explicitly switches the client to a different session.

**Disconnected**: These sessions are still executed on a server but are not connected to a client and, consequently, are not displayed. However, a user can reconnect to a disconnected session, for example by inserting a smart card containing the appropriate token into the card reader on a client. This changes the session's state to connected and causes it to be displayed on that client.

Comment: Is your question how to reconnect a user to his disconnected session when he inserts the cac card back into the machine and hits the website?

Comment: yes that is one part of the question, but the more important part is how the session is automatically disconnected when the user removes the smart card

Answer (score 0):

I think that a similar question has been asked before but I can't find a link (probably something like "flushing ssl sessions when clicking logout"). The key here is SSL (re-)negotiation and SSL session caching.

You have two options: either reduce the SSL session caching from the server (slows down the connections) and thus force a failing re-negotiation sooner when a card is removed (default session cache timeout in Apache mod_ssl was IIRC 300 seconds) or implement a browser plugin (unless you have a dedicated client software) that detects the card removal and thus invalidates the session on the client side (or maybe even sends a signal to the server to flush the session on the server side as well).

If you are talking about a web service, you can never have "full control" with standard tools...

Comment: thanks for the help, can you be more explicite about how to sends a signal to the server to flush the session on the server side

Comment: Another option would be to add some javascript to poll the webserver to keep requesting some tiny bit of text/html (similar to a ping, web app would return some tiny snippet of text).  When the request fails because the CAC card has been removed, then client side knows it's disconnected.  On server side, if you track the pings for each session, and you stop receiving them, you know that the session is disconnected. This is not the most elegant solution, but it is probably easy to implement.

Comment: i searched for java comet solution to poll data to server and disconnect when cac card has been removed and didn't found my way. can you send me a code source of your implementation ?